# Package not found: lib32bz2-1.0

Tags: package-management, software-installation, android-studio

## GOAL

Install Android Developer Studio

## ERROR MESSAGE

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Error Message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

## QUESTIONS

Is the package unavailable (deprecated) or is the command incorrect?  Perhaps there is another explanation which I have not considered.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue not 20 minutes ago. The solution for me was to run `sudo apt-get update` and install the package afterwards.

Comment: Interesting: several attempts were made with sudo apt-get update and the package did not install.  Were your result on 16.04 64-bit?

Comment: @gatorback - yep.